# jquery select class inside parent div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to change the alt of the image, I'm clicking by 
selecting the image's class (***`add_answer`***)

**Note:** ***`.add_answer`*** shows up multiple times inside different containing `div`'s

```
jQuery(function(){   // Add Answer

    jQuery(".add_answer").click(function(){
        var count = $(this).attr("alt");
        count++;
        $('.a_type_'+count+'').show();
        $(this).parents("div:first").$('.add_answer').attr("alt", count);
    }); 

});
```

This line doesn't seem to be working, how do I select this **`add_answer`** class by way of it's parent `div`

```
$(this).parents("div:first").$('.add_answer').attr("alt", count);
```

Anyone else have an idea?

I'm trying having trouble decreasing the `alt` value on the `.add_answer` image when `.destroy_answer` is clicked

```
jQuery(function(){   // Hide Answer

    jQuery(".destroy_answer").click(function(){
        $(this).parents("div:first").hide();
        var count = $('.add_answer').attr("alt");
        count--;
        $('.add_answer',$(this).parent('div:first')).attr('alt',count);


    }); 

});
```

Problem line:

```
$('.add_answer',$(this).parent('div:first')).attr('alt',count);
```

Comment: I have this now

$(this).parents("div:first").find('.add_answer').attr("alt", count);

But i just realized that the div i'm trying to get is not the parent but the parent of the parent div. how do i get that one?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

you can use the parent div as the scope:

```
 $('.add_answer',$(this).parent('div:first')).attr('alt',count);
```

Answer (score 15):

This should work:

```
$(this).parent("div").find(".add_answer").attr("alt", count);
```

Answer (score 5):

You code is almost correct. Required change is to use .find instead of .$ after .parents method. Use of .parent instead of .parents should be avoided, this way your code will be more unobtrusive (precisely - this way img can be non-direct child of the div).

```
$(this).parents('div:eq(0)').find('.add_answer')
```

You can manipulate :eq(0) to select eg third parent div using :eq(2).

Comment: I have this now $(this).parents("div:first").find('.add_answer').attr("alt", count); But i just realized that the div i'm trying to get is not the parent but the parent of the parent div. how do i get that one?