# Moving elements between 2 div's with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I am trying to move `divs` between two containers (**`#one`** and **`#two`**). I can't seem to figure out how to select a `div` which is inside another `div`.

I found a similar [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/394470/jquery-select-class-inside-parent-div) about targeting class inside a `div`. It gave me idea of using parent.

jQuery has  [a large list of selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/), I assume I could use one of them. But I intuitively think I could use something like #one.draggable or some other kind of specifying path.

[Example on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XGHTQ/3/)

**CSS:**

```
div
{
    display:inline;
    background-color:#eee;
}

.draggable
{
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: lime;
    z-index: 2;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    background-color: #333333;
}

#one
{
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: #555555;
    z-index: 1;
    float: left;
}

#two
{
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: #777777;
    z-index: 1;
    float: left;
}
```

**jQuery:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".draggable",$(this).parent("one")).click(function () { 
        // move from "one" to "two"
        $(this).appendTo("#two");
    });

    $(".draggable",$(this).parent("two")).click(function () { 
        // move from "two" to "one"
        $(this).appendTo("#one");
    });
});
```

**HTML:**

```
<div id="one">
    <div class="draggable">1</div>
    <div class="draggable">2</div>
    <div class="draggable">3</div>
</div>

<div id="two">
    <div class="draggable">4</div>
    <div class="draggable">5</div>
    <div class="draggable">6</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'll try to stick to what seems to be the core of your question: use `$('#one .draggable')` (the space is important!) to select all divs with class 'draggable' inside the div with id 'one'.

So your full jQuery code should be:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#one .draggable').click(function () { 
        // move from "one" to "two"
        $(this).appendTo("#two");
    });

    $('#two .draggable').click(function () { 
        // move from "two" to "one"
        $(this).appendTo("#one");
    });
});
```

**UPDATE**

As you noticed, with the code above it's not possible to move the same div again after the first move. The solution is as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#one .draggable').live('click', function () { 
        // move from "one" to "two"
        $(this).appendTo("#two");
    });

    $('#two .draggable').live('click', function () { 
        // move from "two" to "one"
        $(this).appendTo("#one");
    });
});
```

Comment: +1 I did not know this about space. Problem with your answer - after moving a .draggable from "one" to "two" it can't be moved back. It's because of addressing "#two .draggable" which is then apppended to div "one". I found a work-around, by addressing "div.draggable" :)

Comment: The space means "all divs with class draggable which are descendants of the div with id=one". Without the space, you'd be selecting "a div with id=one AND class=draggable". I'm updating the original answer with a solution for the problem you described.

Comment: As of jQuery 1.7, .live() is now deprecated. Better use .on() instead.
http://api.jquery.com/live/